# Do I need quotation marks within square brackets?

Tags: quotation-marks, square-brackets

Let's say the original source says: "They were at the loud, busy, fair. They played many games there."

My adaptation is: "They played many games [at the loud, busy, fair].

Since "at the loud, busy, fair" is taken verbatim from the original source, do I need to write my adaptation as:

"They played many games ['at the loud busy fair']." to indicate that I have taken it verbatim?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're talking about? Square brackets are usually used inside quotations when you're adding or replacing some of the original words. You don't add additional quotes then.

Comment: Quotes take quotation marks, not an explanation of them.

Comment: Edited to clarify. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: I think this should be sufficient:  "They played many games [at the loud, busy, fair]."

Comment: You should indicate how you're using the quotation, as that will affect how it is formatted. If you're quoting it in a paper, you'd be much better doing something like: *She wrote that "[t]hey played many games" at "the loud, busy, fair"*. Not sure if questions about academic referencing/quotation are on-topic here, although to be fair not sure this is about academic referencing because you don't say.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. This is academic referencing, yes. I've gone with a more clear quote like Stuart has presented.